# Failed to connect to MySQL: Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers - SamplePage.php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

For some reason, I can't create the `employeeTable` on the `sample` database when opening the `SamplePage.php` on my Chrome browser from the following link:

http://ec2-13-57-28-240.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamplePage.php

I was able to create my EC2 Instance from the AWS Create an EC2 Instance and Install a Web Server tutorial on the following link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html

I get the following error:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Server sent charset unknown to the client.
> Please, report to the developers.

From what I read, the AWS Linux AMI image has a UTF-8 character set by default and I get the output running this command on my EC2 Instance after connecting to my MySQL DB Instance:

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%';`

```
  Variable_name            | Value                                     
|+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                      |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                      |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-8.0.17.R1/share/charsets/ |
```

I also set my Putty `/.bash_profile` to use the UTF-8 character set, by inputting the configuration as:

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Not sure what is going on as I as, I believe, I followed the complete tutorial on how to create a DB Instance and link to EC2 Instance from this link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/TUT_WebAppWithRDS.html

Comment: What versions of the various components (clients, server, etc)?  Did you recently change cloud services?

Comment: My client is Windows 10. The AWS EC2 Instance is Linux AMI version 1 and DB instance is MySQL 8.0.17. This is my first experience with any cloud services.

Comment: I do notice that the character_set_client, character_set_connection, charcter_set_results, and the character_set_system are utf8, while the character_set_database and character_set_server are utf8mb4. I don't know if this makes a difference?

Comment: I found an article:<https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html> that may be useful, but I am not experienced enough to interpret it, sorry.

Comment: Can someone guide me on how to change my character_set_database value to UTF8 and my character_set_server value to UTF8, to see if that may fix the issue?

Comment: Unless you have some particular need for "utf8mb3", you should use "utf8mb4".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all this work on changing the charset and making sure the charset in the database was set properly was just a dependency on another problem, which was the `mysqli` extension was not properly installed and enabled. I also upgrade the php version to 7.2, which also may have fixed the issue but I am not entirely sure. Maybe someone can verify what the fix was based on what I had done?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Have you have not put any text into the tables yet, then:

```
ALTER TABLE t CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

If you have data in the table, there are about 3 different ways to change the charset.  The tips are here:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

If you have garbage coming out, then see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: I tried to run the command `ALTER TABLE t CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;` but got the following error: `ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected`

Comment: I inputted `USE sample;` then I ran `ALTER TABLE t CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;` I got the following error: `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'sample.t' doesn't exist`. The error is correct, the table does not exist. The `SamplePage.php` is written to create the `employeeTable` but due to the charset on the `sample` database being different (i.e. UTF-8 compared to UTF8mb4) I am not able to create the `employeeTable`. Just want to create the `sample` database with the `employeeTable` like the `SamplePage.php` was designed to do. Sorry, I wasn't clear, earlier.

Comment: Also, is it possible to change the sample database to be a utf-8 character set instead of a utf8mb4? Is there a command to change it? Maybe, this will solve the charset unknown problem.

Comment: I was able to set the `character_set_server` and the `character_set_database` to `utf8mb3` or `utf8`, by running the `SET NAMES 'utf8mb3';` command and the `set character_set_server ='utf8mb3';` command, but I still get the error`Failed to connect to MySQL: Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers
Error creating table.` Maybe, I have to do something to the `SamplePage.php` file to get the char set correct.

Comment: I placed the header `header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");` into the `SamplePage.php` and still get the same error. I think I have run out of ideas, except to create the database again to see if I may have missed something?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing php56 and installing php72 instead. Following are the commands

`sudo yum -y remove php*`

`sudo yum install php72`

`sudo yum install php72-mysqlnd`

`sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, remove PHP 7.4 and replace with 7.2

```
sudo yum -y remove php*
sudo amazon-linux-extras disable php7.4
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable php7.2
yum clean metadata
sudo yum install php php-{pear,cgi,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip,imap}
php -v
sudo apachectl restart
```